# Eclipse GDB Hardware Debugging Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink, eclipse-cdt

What will happen if add cdt-master-7.0.2.zip in eclipse luna instead cdt-8.6.0.zip? Will the cdt debugging work as it does in helios ?

Comment: Most likely it won't even install.

Comment: That said, why would you want to?

Comment: @JonahGraham Because recently we migrated our  eclipse product from Eclipse 3.7 to Eclipse 4.00. In our product we have GDB debugging, this GDB debugging is not working after the migration before it was working perfectly.but now it is giving some null pointer ecception and the exception is not thrown in our customised class it is thrown from the org.eclipse.cdt.debug.gdbjtag.core plugin

Comment: OK, ask that question (as a new question), i.e. put in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and see :-) It is certainly not supported or tested. That said, Eclipse is generally quite good at backwards compatibility at the binary level so it might all work fine.